# .bat file accepting only letters and limited to only 6 characters

Tags: batch-file

I need the script below to accept only letters and allow up to 06 characters, is this validation possible with .bat?

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Menu
ClS
Color 0A
Date /T
Time /T
Echo(
Echo Computador: %ComputerName%        Usuario logado: %UserName%

Echo  ========================
Echo * 1. PRODUCTION PASSWORD *
Echo * 2. TEST PASSWORD       *
Echo * 3. EXIT                * 
Echo  ========================

Echo(
"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /C 123 /N /M "CHOOSE ONE OF THE OPTIONS:"
GoTo opcao%ErrorLevel% 2>NUL||GoTo opcao4
echo.

:opcao1
@echo off
echo ====================================================================
echo.
set /p "login=Enter your login: "
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the issue on your own? please share a [mcve] of your attempts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
echo ====================================================================
echo.
:enterlogin
set /P login=Enter your login: %=%

echo.%login%| findstr /R "[^a-zA-Z]" >nul 2>&1
if ErrorLevel 1 (
 if not "%login:~6%"=="" (
  echo %login% - 6 CHARACTERS OR LESS
  goto enterlogin
 )  
 echo %login% - OK
) ELSE (
 echo %login% - LETTERS ONLY
 goto enterlogin
)
echo OK
pause
```

The `%login:~6%` will check for a maximum length of 6, and the regex is what checks for letters only.  If it doesn't fail either of those tests it completes echoing 'OK' and pausing.  This code will crash with most special characters.  For that to be handled, see below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo ====================================================================
echo.
:enterlogin
set /P "login=Enter your login: %=%"

echo.!login!| findstr /R "[^a-zA-Z]" >nul 2>&1
if ErrorLevel 1 (
 if not "!login:~6!"=="" (
  echo !login! - 6 CHARACTERS OR LESS
  goto enterlogin
 )  
 echo !login! - OK
) ELSE (
 echo !login! - LETTERS ONLY
 goto enterlogin
)
echo OK
pause
```

Comment: code succeeds string length test, fails numerical block

Comment: @T3RR0R what numerical block?

Comment: Is still allowing numbers in password

Comment: @T3RR0R oops yes, I made an edit to make things more streamlined but it actually skipped the logic.  Fixed now and improved.

Comment: If it's correct and functioning then an upvote never goes amiss!

Comment: It fails, tried with login `\..\..\..\..\..\windows\system32\calc.exe`

Comment: Hello guys, Thank you for your help

Below I am sending the code I have assembled so far, I have a doubt that I did not find a solution. I want to limit to enter the exact value of 07 characters, how can I do this?

Another point, is there any way to allow only a few logins on access?

Comment: Hi @LeandrodeMatos no problem but as suggested in your question please accept one of the answers (the tick sign) and upvote both those answers that were helpful

Answer (score 0):

For a comprehensive validation...

```
:opcao1
@echo off
echo ====================================================================
echo.
:enterlogin
set /P login=Enter your login: %=%

:: REM block quotes

SET login | FIND """" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET login=

IF NOT DEFINED login GOTO invlogin

:: REM Block tilde

SET login | FIND "~" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET login=

IF NOT DEFINED login GOTO invlogin

:: REM Test for Spaces (REM out if not required)

IF NOT "%login%"=="%login: =%" GOTO invlogin

:: REM Test for all other standard Symbols. (REM out any you wish to permit)

IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:&=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:(=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:)=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:<=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:>=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:{=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:}=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:]=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:[=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:#=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:^=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:+=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:-=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:/=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:\=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:|=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:$=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:!=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:?=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:@=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:'=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:,=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:.=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:;=%" GOTO invlogin
IF NOT "%login%"=="%login:`=%" GOTO invlogin

:: REM Test length

IF NOT "%login:~6%"=="" GOTO invlogin

:: REM Block Numbers

Setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%a in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) DO (
IF NOT "%login%"=="!login:%%a=!" GOTO invlogin
)

ECHO login succesful.
pause
goto enterlogin

:: REM rest of your program here.

:invlogin
echo "%login%" - LETTERS ONLY AND LESS THAN 6 CHARACTERS
pause
goto enterlogin
```

Comment: You an use regex, and also you should always try to use a whitelist where possible not a blacklist, as it is very easy to miss something in a blacklist

Comment: Reason I favor this approach is that it doesn't crash and burn with entry of characters such as >,<,& etc

Comment: there is merit to the inclusion of findstr as you've used, as it will deal with the one character my approach doesn't cover... !

Answer (score 0):

---

**1)** This code can limit input the actions/logins by using a **`for %%@ in (1,2,3)`** looping.

**2)** Get input length and the Total Letters Present,

**3)** Concatenate Input Length + Letters Present (Joining character strings end-to-end).

**4)** Work with predictive string and check input:

- Example:

```bat
rem for /f get the Variable Length + Total Letters Present in Variable:
If input == 1, 1 characters and lenght == 1 letters == 0
If input == a2, 2 characters and lenght == 2 letters == 1
If input == ab5, 3 characters and lenght == 3 letters == 2
If input == abc4, 4 characters and lenght == 4 letters == 3
If input == abcd5, 5 characters and lenght == 5 letters == 4
If input == abcde6, 6 characters and lenght == 6 letters == 5
```

---

- A valid and prediction string where I've gotten the Variable Length

  and Concatenate with the Total Letters occurs (Length + Total Letters Present in Variable)

  ---

```bat
If input == a, 1 characters and string lenght == 1 letters == 1 concanated == 11 Valid!
If input == ab, 2 characters and string lenght == 2 letters == 2 concanated == 22 Valid!
If input == abc, 3 characters and string lenght == 3 letters == 3 concanated == 33 Valid!
If input == abcd, 4 characters and string lenght == 4 letters == 4 concanated == 44 Valid!
If input == abcde, 5 characters and string lenght == 5 letters == 5 concanated == 55 Valid!
If input == abcdef, 6 characters and string lenght == 6 letters == 6 concanated == 66 Valid!
```

---

- Validating only when the input has only letters, we have the length equal to the number of occurrences of letters in the variable:

  ---

```bat
if "%%h%%i" ==  any (11,22,33,44,55,66) goto :next
| a | ab | abc | abcd | abcde | abcdef |
 11   22    33     44      55       66
 ^^
 ||
 |: ==> %%i number of occurrences of letters in variable: 1 occurrence of letters
 |
 : ===> %%h total length of variable: 1 in length
```

- Using predictive string in loop to validate input length up to 6 and only `Letters` and add action if match.

  ---

```bat
for %%# in (11 22 33 44 55 66)do echo/%%h%%i|findstr /lb "%%#" >nul && goto :next
```

---

**<kbd>Q59709952.cmd</kbd>**

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && break off

cls & title <nul && title [%computername%] ...\%~nx0
for /f %%a in ('echo/prompt $h^|cmd')do set "_b=%%a" 

for %%@ in (1,2,3)do ( 
 echo/ & if %%@ gtr 1 (
      color 4F && %__APPDIR__%rundll32.exe %__APPDIR__%cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub
      echo= -^> ERROR: Input must be up to 06 characters or less and ONLY LETTERS
      echo= -^> Press any key to continue^!! && %__APPDIR__%timeout -1 >nul 
      if %%@ equ 3 echo/ -^> [ !input! - not valid input ^] & endlocal & goto :EOF
     ) 
 color 80 && set "_t=!time:~0,5!" && for /f ^tokens^=^1^delims^=^. %%i in ('
 %__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime^|findstr [0-9]')do set "_dt=%%~i"
 set "_data=!_dt:~6,2!/!_dt:~4,2!/!_dt:~0,4! !_t: =0!" && cls & echo/ & echo/
 echo= ^| Computador: [%computername%] Usuario logado: [%username%]
 set /p "input=^|!_b! ^| [ 0%%@/02 ] !_data! Enter your login: "
 echo/ -----------------------------------------------------
 for /f %%h in ('cmd /u/s/v/c set /p "=!input:  = !"^<nul^|find /v /c ""')do for /f %%i in ('
 cmd/u/s/v/c set/p "=!input:  = !"^<nul^|find /v " "^|%__APPDIR__%findstr [a-Z]^|find /v /c ""
 ')do for %%# in (11 22 33 44 55 66)do echo/%%h%%i|findstr /lb "%%#" >nul && goto :next
)

:next 
echo= [ !input! - OK ] && endlocal && goto :EOF
```